# Within a function, how do I create variables that will accept 2 equally sized matrices and a scalar?

Tags: matlab

```
function[f] = get_f(y,Q,L)
Q = zeros(2)  % creating a 2x2 matrix of zeros
L = diag(zeros(2)) % creating a diagonal matrix
% still playing with how I can pull y in as a scalar, I'm thinking I have
% to assign it earlier in the script where I call this function.
f = expm((Q-L).^y).*L % execution of the function itself
```

How do I tell the function to look for an entered scalar, and 2 equally sized matrices, then execute the listed command?

Answer (score 0):

In your function, `y` is whatever you put as the first argument in your function call.

For instance:

```
get_f(3.14, [1 2; 3 4], [1 0; 0 1])
```

calls the function `get_f` with

- `y = 3.14`
- `Q = [1 2; 3 4]`
- `L = [1 0; 0 1]`

so your function will work.

However, if you want your function to **fail** if `y` is not a scalar or if `Q` and `L` don't have the same size, you can add a condition like this at the beginning of your function:

```
if ~isscalar(y)
    error('y must be a scalar')
end
if any(size(Q) ~= size(L))
    error('Q and L must have the same size')
end
```